# HTML to PDF using iText, formatting issues

Tags: java, itext

I'm working with iText in java to write PDF files. I'm trying to write a paragraph like heading and then text start very after the heading in the same line like

**Heading:** this a para now ...

Heading is bold and para is in normal text but I'm unable to do this using iText. I tried to use:

```
fonts[2] = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, Font.BOLD);
Paragraph paranumber = new Paragraph(
    fonts[2].getCalculatedLeading(1),
    headingText.trim()
                + " ", fonts[0]);

Paragraph para = new Paragraph(
    fonts[0].getCalculatedLeading(1), contentText.trim(), fonts[0]);
        para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        para.setSpacingAfter(3f);

//Now adding the para to paraNumber that is having the heading and expecting
//that it will be added very after the heading, but this does not show correct 
//result, formatting issue.

paranumber.add(para);
mct.addElement(paranumber);
```

I also tried to create a new paragraph and added both paras(heading para and normal text para) to that new one, but that is also not showing proper result. please see below chunk for that.

```
Paragraph newPara = new Paragraph();
newPara.add(paranumber);
newPara.add(para);
```

but this also not show proper formatting.

Or if anyone can **advise me to use some other way to create PDF from HTML** that will be good too, so that i may rewrite the module to create required PDF. Please advise.

Comment: Maybe you need Chunk of different font in the same paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paragraphs typically use concepts like [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)) and increased [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) to set them apart visually.  They are block level elements, not inline.
It doesn't make sense to add a paragraph inside another paragraph.  The added paragraph would typically start on a new line, essentially making it a separate paragraph anyway.

To get a paragraph with different fonts, like your example, you can use `Chunk`s in iText.  A `Chunk` is basically a piece of text with an associated font.

```
Font fontbold = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD,
    BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12);
Font fontregular = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
    BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12);
Chunk header = new Chunk("Heading: ", fontbold);
Chunk content = new Chunk("this is a para now ...", fontregular);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.add(header);
paragraph.add(content);
document.add(paragraph);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Paragraph]

It's not clear from your question and code sample how HTML is involved.  I assume you are somehow parsing HTML input and converting the parsed content to PDF using iText `Element`s. This is a valid approach. Alternatively, you can look into iText XML Worker, which does XHTML (+CSS) to PDF conversion.